# ¿Raycast2D no sirve?

Tags: unity3d

necesito hacer un raycasthit2d sobr euna imagen pero este solo sirve solo cuando muevo la camara manualmente sobre la imagen, peor necesito ahcerlo con la posicion del mouse esto tengo:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class raycast : MonoBehaviour {
 public LayerMask layer;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
RaycastHit2D hit =Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),Vector2.zero);

if(hit.collider != null){
    Debug.Log("yaaaa");
}

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

using UnityEngine.AI;

```
public class MoveToClickPoint : MonoBehaviour {
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start() {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100)) {
                agent.destination = hit.point;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

///https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-MoveToClickPoint.html///

Comment: Hola Albert. La respuesta podria estar bien y dar solucion al problema pero has de explicar mejor qué tenia mal la pregunta y cómo tu respuesta da solucion y funciona. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo